# How to apply BackdropFilter blur entire background except in the center?

Tags: flutter, dart, blur

I am trying to apply the blur effect in all background space except in the center square. How I can do it?

```
child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned.fill(
              child: QRView(
                key: qrKey,
                onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
                overlay: QrScannerOverlayShapeTeste(
                  overlayColor: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.85),
                  borderColor: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: 8,
                  borderLength: 30,
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  cutOutSize: 200,
                  borderRadiusBackground: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: const Radius.circular(12),
                    topRight: const Radius.circular(12),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(
                  sigmaX: 5.0,
                  sigmaY: 5.0,
                ), //this is dependent on the import statment above
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                )
                    ),
              ),
            ),
])
```

[image]

In this picture above, the blur effect is in all my background. The center square does shouldn't have the blur effect :(

Someone can help me? 
I will thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The children of your `Stack` are backwards. The `QRView` should be below the `BackdropFilter` in the list of children.

However, an easier approach would be to make the `QRView` the child of the `BackdropFilter` altogether. If this causes the filter to not take up the entire available space, you could always throw in an intermediary `SizedBox.exand()`.